# Why doesn't C# null check work with structs?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

I usually check nullable types with `if (foo is not null)`, and afterwards I can use `foo` like the non-null type. Why doesn't this work with structs? Even the `!` operator does not help. Is this a bug or am I missing something? What's the shortest workaround?

```
Foo? foo = new Foo { a = "foo" }; 
if (foo is not null) {
    Console.WriteLine(foo.a);  // Works, prints "foo"
}

Bar? bar = new Bar { a = "bar" };
if (bar is not null) {
    Console.WriteLine(bar.a);  // Error: Bar? does not contain a definition for "a"
    Console.WriteLine(bar!.a); // Same error
}

class Foo {
    public string a;
}
struct Bar {
    public string a;
}
```

Comment: Because a nullable struct is of type `Nullable<T>` which is completely different from a nullable reference type. You have to use `.Value` to access the value of a nullable struct.

Comment: What works in both cases is pattern matching: `if (foo is Foo notNullFoo) Console.WriteLine(notNullFoo.a)`.

Comment: And if repeating the type name seems undesirable, `{}` can be used instead: `if (bar is {} notNullBar) Console.WriteLine(notNullBar.a)`. Eliminating `notNullBar` can only be done at the cost of exposing the structural differences between nullable reference types and nullable value types.

Answer (score 4):

**Backwards-compatibility.**

Nullable value types exist since C# 2.0, and they are implemented differently than nullable reference types (since C# 8.0).

- `int?` is a synonym for `Nullable<int>`, which is a completely different type than `int`. There is some compiler magic (lifted operators) to make it behave similarly, but `Nullable<int>` has members that `int` doesn't have (`HasValue`, `Value`) and vice-versa (`ToString(string)`).
- `string?` on the other hand, is of type `string`, with additional compile-time checks enabled.

Making a null-check on `int?` allow you to access the underlying `int` without "unwrapping" it with `.Value` would have broken tons of existing code.

---

You *can*, however, use pattern matching to create a *new* variable with the underlying type:

```
int? a = 3;      // implicit conversion from int to Nullable<int>

if (a is int b)
{
    // Use b to access the underlying int here.
}
else
{
    // a was null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types and cannot be assigned to null. By declaring the struct as nullable you wrap them in a Nullable<T> struct. You should check the HasValue and Value property of the Nullable<Bar> struct in you case.

```
        Bar? bar = new Bar { a = "bar" };
        if (bar.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Value.a);
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Value.a);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct is a value type so it's never null.
You can check the default value for struct